# The Repository Service marked the session or session instance as impacted

Tags: informatica

I am new in control-M. I have a work flow that i developed in Informatica....When i run the work flow in informatica workflow manager itz working fine...but when i scheduled it in Control-M Its making an error -

> The Repository Service marked the session or session instance as
>   impacted, and the Integration Service is not configured to run
>   impacted sessions

What will be the reason for this? If any one knows please help me..that will be very greatful for me....

Regards.....

Answer (score 12):

An impacted session means that the mapping that the session is configured for has been changed, but the session has not been refreshed since. You can fix this easily by right-clicking on the session and choosing 'Refresh Mapping', and then validating the session.

You can alternatively configure the Integration Service to run impacted sessions, but this is not recommended as it will not stop misconfigured sessions from running.

Comment: Hey Datajam... I have not used Control-M but i'm in informatica.. here with Sinoy issue is because of impact session.. This means impact session is error thrown by informatica or by conrtrol-M... If its informatica how it ran fine in his case??? you mean is ran with previous session???

Comment: I'm not sure where the confusion lies, but an impacted session is certainly nothing to do with Control-M, which I assume is simply issuing a pmcmd command to run the workflow that contains the impacted session.

Comment: Thanks Shanmugam and Datajam for your kind replies....Still i got the same issue ...when i run this workflow manually itz working perfectly...but when it scheduled to control M it populates the error. I am working with windows...I tried the validate option and all. But no change...

Comment: How are you running the workflow manually? Does the workflow have multiple sessions?

Comment: After your refresh the session with change mapping, remember to checkin the workflow. Your control-m is still pointing to older version of workflow it seems.

Comment: How does one go about validating a session? Is there a menu somewhere inthe RDWM windows or does it have to be done by the command line?

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem, but the solution was a little bit different.

I had one of the shortcuts components checked out. So Even If I had checked in everthing from mapping to workflow. The repository service had marked the session as impacted.

So after checking in the shortcuts I was able to run the mapping. 
Regards, 
Vic

Comment: This was my problem as well, and it took frustratingly long to find it because the object I had checked out (an email task) is not used in the workflow whose session was reported as impacted, and didn't show up in "Find dependencies..." from Workflow Manager. The mysterious dependency appeared only in Designer, and checking in that email task solved it.

Answer (score 2):

Another possible fix:

After the source or target definitions were updated in the mapping within Developer PowerCenter, I did this in Workflow Manager.

Checkout workflow > right click task > Refresh Mapping > Validate

Then I had to go and fix the connection strings for each source and target that I changed in Developer PowerCenter.

Answer (score 1):

This might be due to you are running the workflow in checkout mode.

- If you are running manually, it will take checkout version.
- If you are running through control-M it will take previous checkin version, it might be impacted.

Please check for if it is checkin or checkout.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout workflow -> Validate -> **Ctrl+S** -> Check in workflow

Answer (score 0):

Check 2 things:

1. Edit Session -> mapping-> source-> connections

   Is connection correct? If it isn't, choice the correct connection.
2. Edit Session -> config object-> error handling-> override tracing

   After to get session log, we can forget the settings that taking back to "override tracing = None" from "override tracing = Verbose"